# Elasticsearch: Unknown time in date field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Im parsing date from a csv file and populating in elastic.
This is how I defined date field in index:

```
    PUT Index_1
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "Date":{
          "type":"date",
          "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
      }
}
}
}
```

The  CSV file has data in yyyy-MM-dd format.
Once data is in elastic I am getting an unknown time along with the date.
For eg: for my date entry in csv as 2018-02-02, I am seeing data in elastic as 
Date:February 2nd 2018, 05:30:00.000. Is there a way I can get rid of "05:30:00.000".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 05:30:00 default is your time zone. ElasticSearch asumes the zone to be UTC by default. If you are viewing the data with Kibana, then Kibana converts the time to the local timezone (from the browser). You can't "get rid" of it, but you can enforce a fixed timezone (say UTC, which will show as 00:00:00) from Kibana's Management settings.